# Interfacing peripheral drivers with RTOS

Tags: driver, stm32, rtos

For one of my project the controller selection made was STM32L1 series. ST provides the drivers for USB, I2C, SPI etc. So while making a decision on RTOS is there any consideration needed to be given to the drivers. Or in another way after deciding an RTOS, is there any standard way of interfacing peripheral drivers of the microcontroller with RTOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, microcontroller peripheral drivers and the RTOS are typically independent so compatibility doesn't need to be a consideration.  The microcontroller peripheral drivers are basic drivers that aren't reliant on any RTOS services.  In fact the peripheral library can be used without any RTOS.  And an RTOS typically does not rely on any microcontroller peripherals beyond a timer.  Even the setup of the timer is not built-in to the RTOS.  The timer is typically setup by user code, before starting the RTOS.

If I haven't convinced you and you still want some assurance of compatibility then explore [CMSIS](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php).

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard defined way to interface peripheral drivers to an RTOS as it depends on the RTOS. However, a common way is to take advantage of blocking mutex or semaphore that are provided by the RTOS. A blocking mutex means that if a mutex is not available, a task will wait until it is free and not use any CPU time until then.

Usually when running an RTOS, you want the peripheral driver to grab the input data as quickly as possibly, using an interrupt, and then pass off the data to an RTOS task that can take its time processing the data. This is a nice clean way of managing peripheral interrupts and RTOS multitasking.

The general scenario is then you have a task that waits on the mutex. Most of the time it does not take any CPU time. When a peripheral driver gets invoked by an interrupt, the driver grabs the data off the hardware, and frees the mutex so the waiting task will wake up. The actual data can be passed between the peripheral driver and the task using global variable or other RTOS defined mechanism. Similar mechanism can be done using a semaphore.

The ST's provided peripheral drivers (whether it is StdPeripheralLib, HAL, or LL) can operate in this model. Therefore when making a decision on which RTOS to use, you should consider an RTOS with API that supports this model.

Answer (score 1):

While ST's low level drivers do not have RTOS dependencies or requirements, you might build a higer-level driver architecture around these using RTOS mechanisms to support mutual exclusion, buffering, and to manager handler priority for example.

You could for example manage multi-thread access to a device either through a device manager thread, or via mutual exclusion.